# How to create text on a semi-transparent overlay with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have Blender 2.73a and I am working on a movie project. I want to make HUD-like text since there are no voiceovers. I want the text to be like it is in The Legend of Zelda where it displays the text since that has no voiceovers also. It will be something like this [image]
<sub>(source: [deviantart.net](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/162/b/d/_gif_you_ve_met_with_a_terrible_fate__haven_t_you__by_repee-d7ly25i.jpg))</sub>  .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a text object and a plane that is translucent/transparent.

[image]

Add a copy rotation constraint using the camera as target (so that both objects are parallel to the camera).

[image]

Material for the plane:

[image]

Material for the text:

[image]

If you have a lot of titles you might need to create the titles as a separate scene and render each one as a PNG file to composite later.

[image]

Comment: This is a feasible hack, but unfortunately not a nice one: It is hard to switch the text during the movie. Furthermore you have to use even more hacky techniques to keep the text at a cut (changing camera/perspective).

Answer (score 3):

## Overlays are easy!

This is a classic case for post processing.
Since Blender isn't the choice for typesetting 2D-Text, the overlay text should be made with a different program (this here was made with GIMP):
[image: overlay]

notice that the background is transparent.
Next follows your blender scene, for example

[image: scene]

The right way of overlaying text (also subtitles) for movies is with the sequencer:

1. create a new (empty) scene
2. go to the `Video Sequencer`
3. `Add` > `Scene` > `[Name of your first scene]`
4. `Add` > `Image` > choose your previously created overlay
5. set the Blend-mode to `Alpha Over`

This way changing your characters speech bubble is easy by just overlaying a different text:

[image: sequencer]

You can let your characters speak even with changing camera because the text is overlayed in the video sequencer.
Here you see the result: suzanne speaking

[image: result]