# How to make text fade in and out

Tags: video, transparency, text-object

I recently asked a question on how to make [text with a transparent overlay](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28065/how-to-create-text-on-a-transparent-overlay-with-cycles) and I was wondering if I can make that text fade in and out. An example of it is on the first part of [this video](https://youtu.be/Cz3U5K9dKD0) (the text).

Answer (score 1):

If you mix a diffuse and transparent shader together you can animate the mix value so that the material goes from visible to invisible. Mouse over the mix value and press the <kbd>I</kbd> key to create a **Keyframe**, move to the frame where you want the text to be completely invisible and press the <kbd>I</kbd> key again .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The text in the video you refer to is text being added, rather than being faded in, this is often referred to as a typewriter effect.

Ben Simmonds has made his [randomiser addon](https://github.com/BenSimonds/Randomiser) available that can easily do the typewriter effect.

[This short video](https://youtu.be/Jg93ksWYKws) demonstrates some possibilities of the addon. You can also find a link to a tutorial video on the github page.

Comment: I'm having issues with the plugin, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the typewriter add on is no longer included in the latest version of Blender, I too wanted to achieve this effect without having to reinstall more add ons. So the Build modifier came to my rescue. With a few simple adjustments the build modifier will give you the same results. I have a Tutorial on it here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvavBLng6CE

Hope it helps..

Edit: Here is a quick run down of the steps -

Go to top view, align your camera and Position your text around the scene. (It's important to create more then one text object if you want the text to appear line by line).. Then convert each text object to a mesh (Alt+c). Then add a build modifier to them.

Then (Tab) into edit mode and select everything (Make sure you have "Face Select" mode selected) then hit space bar and type "Sort" select sort mesh elements > View X Axis.

Then you want to set the timing for each of your build modifiers. Lets say the length can be 25f and the start is changed on each so that when the top one ends the one underneath begins.

I'm sure the tutorial can explain things better but here is a simple run down of how to do it..

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as if the link goes down then so does the answer. Please include some of the steps in the answer body itself.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for letting me know!.. I'm not sure I explained it all too well but the video will certainly help.