# Making an Invisible Material in the Cycles render engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm a newcomer to Blender and have created a scene in which I want to animate the disappearance of an object. I don't know if this is the 'right' way to do this, but I managed to get the desired effect by having a big block move over the object to be disappeared, and I added a boolean Difference modifier to the object to be disappeared.

This gets me the effect that I want, but I haven't been able to get my big block 100% transparent. It's almost, but not quite, entirely unlike a solid object, but it still casts a shadow and appears to have other visual effects on the animation that I don't fully understand.

Can anyone hand-hold me through creating an absolutely invisible material for my big block, or teach me the 'correct' way to accomplish my goals?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of using the big block? Is because you need a particular fade-out transition? What is it? Anyway a simple transparent shader set to full white color (by default is 90%white) should be completly invisible.

Comment: Possible related questions: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30458/how-to-make-text-fade-in-and-out and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35734/how-to-animate-text-being-revealed-on-the-screen/35740#35740

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5113/599

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## A few options

1- Make the big cube unrenderable by switching off the camera icon:

[image]

2- Move the big cube to a different layer that is not renderable

3- Make the shader for the BIG CUBE a holdout material (then you don't need the boolean)

4- Turn off all Ray Visibility for the object in the properties panel.

[image]

5- Use the [object as mask](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-use-an-object-as-a-mask) (no need for boolean either)

Comment: Making the object un-render-able was a quick and effective solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want the object to disappear gradually I would do it with the material.  To make it disappear from top to bottom/side to side etc. (like a box covering it up as you described) I would se this node setup for it's material.

[image]

You can then animate the value on the *greater than* node (the one in yellow) from `1` to `0` to make the object disappear from top to bottom.  If you want left to right use the X value from the *separate XYZ* node.

[image]

This works because taking the X, Y, or Z component of the [generated texture coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/what-methods-can-be-used-to-place-a-texture-onto-an-object/23174#23174) gives a gradient from `0` to `1` from left to right, front to back, or back to front respectively.  The output of this, sent through a greater than node to chop it off at a certain point, is used to drive a mix shader mixing the normal material (in this case the diffuse shader) with a transparent shader.  When you animate the value of the greater than node you are animating the cutoff point.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of a work-around, in the materials tab (on the right) set the node to mix shader.

Add a transparent shader to each one. I'm presuming this works by making it at 50% of it's transparency, then adding a second one makes the transparency 0%